# python-social-auth Twitter login returns Authenitcation Failed

Tags: python, django, twitter, python-social-auth

I'm trying to use python-social-auth to register and login users through Google, Facebook and Twitter (initially). Google and Facebook are working but with Twitter I'm getting the following error:

> AuthFailed at /login/twitter/
>
> Authentication failed: ('bad handshake:SysCallError(0, None)',)

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py" in wrapper
  50.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/views.py" in auth
  19.     return do_auth(request.backend, redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME)

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/actions.py" in do_auth
  27.     return backend.start()

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py" in start
  34.             return self.strategy.redirect(self.auth_url())

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py" in auth_url
  166.         token = self.set_unauthorized_token()

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py" in set_unauthorized_token
  222.         token = self.unauthorized_token()

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py" in unauthorized_token
  246.             method=self.REQUEST_TOKEN_METHOD

File "/var/www/ian/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py" in request
  222.             raise AuthFailed(self, str(err))

Exception Type: AuthFailed at /login/twitter/
Exception Value: Authentication failed: ('bad handshake: SysCallError(0, None)',)
```

My HTML link is through:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>Sign in with Twitter</a>
```

My `urls.py` is:

```
url(r'', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

And my `settings.py` has the following changes:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'social_django',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = '6pdiYC2jCocUD7JarM0NbeGuR'
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = 'Z2yTHmjB2jDvRSSXwJ0kFpAVjTn2UCsSJW8USIkQnGaVegzviw'
```

I think my error is somewhere in the `settings.py` because I've had a couple of others in there, but I cannot find it.

Please help, I've been at this for 7 hours and can't work it out.

**EDIT**

I really do not understand what is going on because it has suddenly started working from my laptop using django development server but I continue to get the error when running from a VPS.

**EDIT**

And if I refresh the screen twice (using F5 key) it logs in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things (I do not know which solved the issue) which seems to have sorted this.  (Note: I've marked these a blockquotes because it wasn't showing as code otherwise and because unreadable)

1. Potentially the error occurred because of lack of memory.  The swap files sorts that

> ```
> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=524288 
> sudo chmod 600 /swapfile 
> sudo mkswap /swapfile 
> sudo swapon /swapfile
> ```

2. Adding this to the Apache conf file

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/path/to/wsgi>
>     <Files wsgi.py>
>         Require all granted
>     </Files>
>     WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
> </Directory>
> ```